# Completely Remove All Microsoft Visio 2013 Leftover Files

Tags: windows-registry, reinstall, microsoft-visio, microsoft-visio-2013

I am having a problem with my Microsoft Visio 2013 installation, and I would like to completely wipe my computer of all leftover files that remain from doing a traditional uninstall. How could I do this? Whatever files are left are left over from uninstalling and reinstalling are causing problems.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There used to be a MS Office Uninstallation Tool.  It appears to be replaced with a new tool.

http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall

Comment: I've seen this, but on my computer, the "Run Now" button is disabled, and under it there's a message saying "We're sorry, but your operating system is not supported by Microsoft Fix it at this time." Just in case I neglected to mention it before, my operating system is Windows 8.1 Professional 64 bit.

Comment: Okay, I used another computer to download the portable version of Microsoft Fix it, and I am attempting to use the Install & Uninstall Troubleshooter to remove Visio. Will this remove other files that are normally left behind from an installation? As I was typing this, the process just finished, saying that the process was complete, now to see if it worked.

Comment: It did not work. Any ideas?

Comment: No...  I used to use the uninstaller tool.  havent tried this new tool.  Is there something specific that is causing an issue?  is there an error message?

Comment: I do not have an error message. I used a key finder to get the key for my Visio installation, which I have long lost. Whenever I type the key into the box, I get a green check mark, but when I submit the key, Visio still lists itself as deactivated. Restarting the program or the entire computer does not change the results. What I would like to do is completely wipe off all traces of my previous Office & Visio installation. My Office installation is fine, but I want to reinstall it as well so that I can get a clean install of everything.

Answer (score 2):

Finally!!!!!

I have been trying to fix this issue for days.

I have Office 2013 and Visio 2013. I was uninstalling both Office and Visio for a re-install to fix another issue I was having with Outlook. During the Visio uninstall, my laptop ran out of battery and hibernated. Since then, the Visio install would just crash. No warning, no error message, nothing. The install window would just close. It showed in the programs list, that Visio was still installed, but when trying to run it, I received a message that said "the operating system is not presently configured to run this application".

After many attempts to fix the registry and use specific microsoft fixit applications, I tried using both of these fixits:

http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2013_release-office_install/office-2013-visio-2013-and-ms-project-2013-will/a2dbb2c9-1cff-4afc-b619-a04e18df1289

and running the 2010 fixit here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971179

finally the Visio installation stopped crashing and completed successfully.